# A local variable is still accessible out the function?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

```
function x() {
    if(true) {
         var y = "hello world";
    }
    alert(y);
}
x()
alert(y)
```

When I run this code, it alerts twice "Hello world".

I read tutorials about scopes and by them `y` should not be accessible to the second alert.

Why is it accessiable? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It's not. Are you sure you don't also define `y` outside the function?

Comment: When I run your code I get one alert with hello world: http://jsfiddle.net/Q9eFU/ There should be another y definition outside the x() scope

Comment: I have just tried. it shows only one alert

Comment: @Blackhole This is the whole code. im using firefox

Comment: How do you run this code? Using scratchpad?

Comment: Then you have to remember, All the variables in the page and variables you defined  earlier are in the memory and are defined!, Close you firefox, Open new scartchpad and test it there!

Comment: @undone My fault. did it and getting reference exception. thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't alert twice. (I actually tested this in IE, Firefox and Chrome to be absolutely sure.)

The variable is local to the function, so trying to use it outside the function causes a reference error.

---

If you actually see that behavoir, then it's because you already have defined a variable by the same name with the same value in the global scope also.

Comment: @user1798362: That should not make any difference for something that is so fundamental to the Javascript language. There are plenty of browswer differences, but very few in the Javascript language itself.

Answer (score 0):

The variable y should not be accessible outside the function. When I tested it it wasn't accessible.

You might actually have the variable y defined somewhere in the global scope as well and that might be what's being alerted.

Local variables in JavaScript are accessible only to local scope, while global variables (those defined outside the functions) are accessible everywhere, even inside functions.

In your case I suspect there might be another "y" variable defined somewhere in the global scope.

---

*Also are you sure you are not running your script twice? In this case you might be getting the alert twice from two calls to the x() function.*

Another reason is that there might be another script that you are running on your page that has a y variable defined in its global scope and when it's combined with this script it would alert the y variable defined in the global scope of the other script.